# reload page on change of dropdown and pass that value

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown in my page.When I select an option from dropdown the page should reload and come back to same page and the value of that dropdown should be passed
Below is the php code for dropdown

```
<select style="width: 200px;" name="location" onchange="window.location='index.php?id=' + this.value;">
    <option value="All">All</option>
    <option value="Noida Sector 1">Noida Sector 1</option>
    <option value="Noida Sector 2">Noida Sector 2</option>
    <option value="Noida Sector 3">Noida Sector 3</option>
    <option value="Noida Sector 4">Noida Sector 4</option>
    <option value="Noida Sector 5">Noida Sector 5</option>
    <option value="Noida Sector 6">Noida Sector 6</option>
    <option value="Noida Sector 7">Noida Sector 7</option>
</select>

<?php $location=$_POST['id']; ?>
```

I am trying to pass the value to $location.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change your php code ,this code outputs selection option and highlights selected value(shown below)

```
    <select style="width: 200px;" id="myselect" name="location" onchange="window.location='index.php?id='+this.value+'&pos='+this.selectedIndex;">
        <option value="All">All</option>
        <option value="Noida Sector 1">Noida Sector 1</option>
        <option value="Noida Sector 2">Noida Sector 2</option>
        <option value="Noida Sector 3">Noida Sector 3</option>
        <option value="Noida Sector 4">Noida Sector 4</option>
        <option value="Noida Sector 5">Noida Sector 5</option>
        <option value="Noida Sector 6">Noida Sector 6</option>
        <option value="Noida Sector 7">Noida Sector 7</option>
    </select>

    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['id']))
    {
        $location=$_GET['id'];
        echo $location;
    ?>
    <script>
        var myselect = document.getElementById("myselect");
        myselect.options.selectedIndex = <?php echo $_GET["pos"]; ?>
    </script>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: After reload my dropdown comes back to option 1 but I dont want that I want it to remain selected on the option it was selected.eg if i choose Noida sector 3 then after reload my default selection should be Noida sector 3

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghkainth... updated my code, please vote up if you are happy :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is it an option for you to put the select in a form (action=POST)?
The you could do this (using jquery):

```
$('select').on('change', function () {
    $(this).parent().submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code,

`<?php if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    echo $_GET['id'];
} ?>`

Answer (score 0):

@ Prabhjot Singh kainth, Use like this code,

```
<option value="Noida Sector 3" <?php if ($_GET['id']=='Noida Sector 3'): ?>
selected=selected   
<?php endif ?>>Noida Sector 3</option>
```